# Refresh lightning component when tab is changed

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-tabset

I have created tabs using lightning tabset. I wanted to refresh the component whenever the tab is changes. I tried using `$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();` in tabset onselect event. But it is not working as expected. Can someone help me how to refresh the component whenever tab is changed... Thanks in Advance.

[image: Here is the tabs I am using]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe these are custom Aura component inside the `lightning:tabset`.

And you want to fetch new data from database on select of the active tab?
If this is the case, firing `$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();` wont help. This just refreshes the standard components data.

What you can do is `<lightning:tabset onselect="{! c.handleSelect }" variant="scoped">` use `onselect` to fire your `apex action` again, orelse you can have a refresh button to call the `apex action` again to refresh the data in the custom aura component.

Comment: Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

"onselect" is not possible atm. Try "onactive" attribute for lightning:tabset.